# Excel 2007 PC VBA -- Error 6 Overflow

Tags: excel, vba

Getting an Error 6 - Overflow with Excel VBA.  Normally, that's due to an integer that ought've been a long.  But this... I'm just trying to multiply three numbers together and put the result in a cell.  There's no variable involved.

This is the line it errors on:  wsResults.Cells(4, 3).Value = (60 * 60 * 24)

I've tried closing Excel and re-opening the workbook, and I've tried putting the formula directly into the formula bar (it displayed correctly), but the VBA code still won't work.

Anybody have any ideas?  Thanks!

```
Option Explicit

'Worsheets:
Dim wbThis As ThisWorkbook
Dim wsResults As Worksheet

'Set Timekeeping Values:
Public Const GameTick As Single = (60 / 12) / 4
Public Const GameRound As Single = GameTick * 12
Public Const GameHour As Single = GameRound * 60
Public Const GameDay As Single = GameHour * 24
Public Const GameWeek As Single = GameDay * 7
Public Const GameMonth As Single = GameDay * 30
Public Const GameYear As Single = GameDay * 365

Public Sub TimeControl()

'Initialize Timer:
Randomize Timer

'Set Worksheets:
Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
Set wsResults = wbThis.Sheets("Results")

'Clear wsResults:
wsResults.Range("A1:M1000").ClearContents

'Display Unit Names:
wsResults.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Tick"
wsResults.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Round"
wsResults.Cells(3, 1).Value = "Hour"
wsResults.Cells(4, 1).Value = "Day"
wsResults.Cells(5, 1).Value = "Week"
wsResults.Cells(6, 1).Value = "Month"
wsResults.Cells(7, 1).Value = "Year"

'Display Game Units:
wsResults.Cells(1, 2).Value = GameTick
wsResults.Cells(2, 2).Value = GameRound
wsResults.Cells(3, 2).Value = GameHour
wsResults.Cells(4, 2).Value = GameDay
wsResults.Cells(5, 2).Value = GameWeek
wsResults.Cells(6, 2).Value = GameMonth
wsResults.Cells(7, 2).Value = GameYear

'Display Real-World Units:
wsResults.Cells(1, 3).Value = ""
wsResults.Cells(2, 3).Value = 60
wsResults.Cells(3, 3).Value = (60 * 60)
wsResults.Cells(4, 3).Value = (60 * 60 * 24)
wsResults.Cells(5, 3).Value = (60 * 60 * 24 * 7)
wsResults.Cells(6, 3).Value = (60 * 60 * 24 * 30)
wsResults.Cells(7, 3).Value = (60 * 60 * 24 * 365)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Specifics**

An overflow results when you try to make an assignment that exceeds the limitations of the target of the assignment. This error has the following causes and solutions:

The result of an assignment, calculation, or data type conversion is too large to be represented within the range of values allowed for that type of variable.

Assign the value to a variable of a type that can hold a larger range of values.

An assignment to a property exceeds the maximum value the property can accept.

Make sure your assignment fits the range for the property to which it is made.
You attempt to use a number in a calculation, and that number is coerced into an integer, but the result is larger than an integer. 
For example:

```
Dim x As Long
x = 2000 * 365   ' Error: Overflow
```

To work around this situation, type the number, like this:

```
Dim x As Long
x = CLng(2000) * 365
```

In your case try using this

```
wsResults.Cells(4, 3).Value = CLng(60 * 60) * 24
wsResults.Cells(5, 3).Value = CLng(60 * 60) * 24 * 7
wsResults.Cells(6, 3).Value = CLng(60 * 60) * 24 * 30
...
```

### Edit

**Why does this conversion required ?**

60, 60 and 24 all are Integer values. In `VBA`, Integers are 16-bit signed types, when you perform arithmetic on 2 integers the arithmetic is carried out in 16-bits. Since the result of multiplying these two numbers exceeds the value that can be represented with 16 bits you get an exception.

The second example ( conversion with CLng )works because the first number is first converted to a 32-bit type and the arithmetic is then carried out using 32-bit numbers.

In your example, the arithmetic is being performed with 16-bit integers and the result is then being converted to long but at that point it is too late, the overflow has already occurred. The solution is to convert one of the operands in the multiplication to long first.

Comment: Basically here is the list of type conversion functions which can be used in macro to avoid such kind of overflow error. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx . Since you have been doing this in the excel formulas, it is not required but the excel cell formula itself is capable enough of doing the right kind of conversion for you.

Comment: If the above answer solve your problem you can always mark it as accepted so others can see it as accepted and resolved. Thanks !

Comment: Well, that works.  Thanks!  I've never run into that before.  Looking over my old code, I've always had some counter or other variable that was declared as a long when working with large values.  Good to know that straight multiplication can goof the whole thing.